# How can I input each line of a text file into mutiple output text files?

Tags: batch-file, text-files

So im using batch scripts. What I need to do is this:
I have a servers.txt file with 100+ server names(1 in each line.. so 100+ lines in the textfile). I need to output the server names in different text files. So basically, I want 100+ textfiles with each file having the server name in them.

How can I do this using batch?

Comment: Pls read my comment under Jon's. Pretty much what I did is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the server names are unique, I think you can do something like this:

```
@Echo Off
Set _InputFile=servers.txt
for /f %%a in (_InputFile) do ECHO %%a >> %%a.txt
```

Or if they were all on one line with a delimiter, say a comma:

```
@Echo Off
Set _InputFile=servers.txt    
for /f "delims=," %%a in _InputFile do ECHO %%a >> %%a.txt
```

Comment: This is in a batch script btw, say servers.bat

Comment: hmm... I got this working. So basically this is what i did:
                                                                  FOR /f %%a in (servers.txt) do echo %%a >servicelist%%a.txt  this is really similar to what u said.. although for some reason you are using "/f" instead of "%%a"

Comment: Oops sorry that's a typo. Feel free to mark it as correct now though! =P

Answer (score 0):

Using notepad++ you can quickly type most of this using a macro.

```
@echo off
set Counter=1
(
set /p Server1=
set /p server2=
set /p server3=
set /p server4=
::This pattern continued for every line in the file or longer
)<Servers.txt
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:loop
echo !Server%Counter%!>!Server%Counter%!.txt
set /a Counter=%Counter%+1
if /i %Counter% GTR (Insert Number of files to be made here) goto out
goto loop
:out
ENDLOCAL
echo Job Successful!
pause
```

And there you have it. also with notepad++ you can open your servers.txt file and quickly find out how many lines there are. the number is at the bottom of the screen.